# In Graphic scene how to make overlapped object transparent?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

In graphics view m setting scene in that adding objects (by dropping ), i can move these items by mouse, when i moved one object on another object moved object should be transparent. how can i make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you actually want full transparency since it will make it impossible to visually recognize the transparent object later on. Reduced opacity - yes.

As for your question: each item inside your scene has a bounding rectangle (or other type of bounding area). You can easily get it by calling `boundingRect()` of your item. The returned `QRectF` has (just like `QRect`) has the [`bool QRect::intersects(const QRect &rectangle) const`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#intersects) function, which takes another rectangle and checks if a collision is present.

Whenever you move your mouse while dragging an item you need to iterate either through all or just a subset of all items in your scene (by subset I mean just the items in a specific region to increase the performance) and check for collision. If a collision is detected, you can alter either the item you are dragging or the item underneath it.

Of course to make sure that one item covers another one you also need to check the Z value. The easiest way to do that is if you keep all currently not being dragged items at the same Z level and then, whenever you drag one, increase it's Z level by one so that it is "above" the others.